# How to sort values that has different position of the fields in bash

Tags: bash

I discovered looking at my logs; that the commits to git may have or not have a name and last name; which means that if I sort using -k, the position of the fields may not be correct.

For example, if i get a file with commits to various repository the standard format that I have is

commit - name - surname - date - repo name

I sort them with sort -k 4, so I get them ordered by date (that's what I need)/

Problem is, sometimes the committer name is replaced by a generic name (not sure why, I am not managing the repository); so it ends up jumping one field, and the date is now on the 3rd position, not the 4th.

This results in the majority of the commits ordered correctly, but the ones that has the date on the 3rd position, end up being at the bottom, so I don't have them ordered chronologically.

Since I cannot control what the repo throw at me, is there a way to tell sort, to order by date, without specify which one is the field that has the date?
Or should I use something different from sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just check the number of fields on the line?   I.e. counting from the last element instead of from the first?

Granted that `sort` may not have sufficient capabilities to specify keys from the end of line, so you may have to resort to a small awk script to find the the right sort key based on the number of records in each line.

Like;

```
# Reorder fields to be date - reponame - commit - name - surname(optional)
awk '{
    if (NF==4) print $3, $4, $1, $2; 
    else print $4, $5, $1, $2, $3;
}' file.log | sort -k1
```

Comment: Good point; how do I tell sort to use the -k parameter but from the right instead of left? from the right, it is always the second field, so problem solved in that case. Awk works too, altho I was going for the shortest solution. Trying now. Thanks!

Comment: In the (updated) answer the fields will be shuffled so the variable/optional fields is in the end -- i.e. changing the order of fields --  so the problem goes away.